# Xtext: check if EObject defined in a file or not

Tags: plugins, xtext

I have an EObject and I want to find out if it's defined in a file (I have the path for it)
How I can do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`element.eResource().getURI()` returns a uri for a resource to which the element belongs to